# Any package to run VAR-GARCH or VECM-GARCH models in R?

Tags: r, garch, value-at-risk, econometrics, multivariate

I need to estimate a multivariate VECM-GARCH (or simply VAR-GARCH) in R.

Browsing on the internet, I did not find anything yet.

Do you know if such kind of packages exists?

Please, note that a BEKK approach is required since I am working on some optimal hedge ratio calculation and volatility analysis.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it exists and it is called `ccgarch` package.

You can install that by simply running in R `install.packages("ccgarch")` and learn more about that on the [CRAN relative paper](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ccgarch/ccgarch.pdf).

Moreover, I suggest you to read this [lecture](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2008/slides/Nakatani.pdf) hold by the author during an R conference.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I went through the package and its slides. it is mentioned that the covariance estimation has direct vecm and bekk representation, yet the result seems not to be a vecm-garch (bekk). Do you know if this package is following the BEKK approach?

Comment: This is the answer from ccgarch author: The ccgarch package is designed only for estimating constant and dynamic conditional correlation GARCH models, so that it is not able to estimate BEKK or vech GARCH model.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using mgarchBEKK (or mgarch) but it seems like the package firstly estimate the VECM model, then use the residuals (Epsilon t) of the VECM (and their variances) in estimating the BEKK-GARCH model. 
I believe the correct method is to run the two models as a system, but I do not know how to proceed! Can anyone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 0):

The `MTS` package has the fucntion to fit a `BEKK(1,1)` but i would recommend that you use a `dcc-garch` which has less problems that the BEKK approach an it is faster to run